# I tried to automate json views in snowflake. But it displays error in the regex

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried this approach and it is displaying an error that the regex has a missing statement. The approach that I am trying is from the Automating Snowflake’s Semi-Structured JSON Data Handling

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_view_over_json (TABLE_NAME varchar, COL_NAME varchar, VIEW_NAME varchar, COLUMN_CASE varchar, COLUMN_TYPE varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$

var alias_dbl_quote = "";
var path_name = "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(f.path,'\\[(.+)\\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"')"   // This generates paths with levels enclosed by double quotes (ex: "path"."to"."element").  It also strips any bracket-enclosed array element references (like "[0]")
var attribute_type = "DECODE (substr(typeof(f.value),1,1),'A','ARRAY','B','BOOLEAN','I','FLOAT','D','FLOAT','STRING')";    // This generates column datatypes of ARRAY, BOOLEAN, FLOAT, and STRING only
var alias_name = "REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(f.path, '\\[(.+)\\]'),'[^a-zA-Z0-9]','_')" ;                           // This generates column aliases based on the path
var table_list = TABLE_NAME;
var col_list = "";
var array_num = 0;

if (COLUMN_CASE.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'M') {
   alias_dbl_quote = """; }          // COLUMN_CASE parameter is set to 'match col case' so add double quotes around view column alias name 
if (COLUMN_TYPE.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'S') {
   attribute_type = "DECODE (typeof(f.value),'ARRAY','ARRAY','STRING')"; }   // COLUMN_TYPE parameter is set to 'string datatypes' so typecast to STRING instead of value returned by TYPEPOF function

// Build a query that returns a list of elements which will be used to build the column list for the CREATE VIEW statement
var element_query = "SELECT DISTINCT n" +
                    path_name + " AS path_name, n" +
                    attribute_type + " AS attribute_type, n" +
                    alias_name + " AS alias_name n" +
                    "FROM n" + 
                    TABLE_NAME + ", n" +
                    "LATERAL FLATTEN(" + COL_NAME + ", RECURSIVE=>true) f n" +
                    "WHERE TYPEOF(f.value) != 'OBJECT' n" +
                    "AND NOT contains(f.path,'[') ";      // This prevents traversal down into arrays

// Run the query...
var element_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:element_query});
var element_res = element_stmt.execute();

// ...And loop through the list that was returned
while (element_res.next()) {
   

   if (element_res.getColumnValue(2) != 'ARRAY') {
      if (col_list != "") {
         col_list += ", n";}
      col_list += COL_NAME + ":" + element_res.getColumnValue(1);                               // Start with the element path name
      col_list += "::" + element_res.getColumnValue(2);                                         // Add the datatype
      col_list += " as " + alias_dbl_quote + element_res.getColumnValue(3) + alias_dbl_quote;   // And finally the element alias 
   }

// Array elements get handled in the following section:
   else {
      array_num++;
      var simple_array_col_list = "";
      var object_array_col_list = "";

// Build a query that returns the elements in the current array
      var array_query = "SELECT DISTINCT n"+
                         path_name + " AS path_name, n" +
                         attribute_type + " AS attribute_type, n" +
                         alias_name + " AS attribute_name, n" +
                         "f.index n" +
                         "FROM n" + 
                         TABLE_NAME + ", n" +
                         "LATERAL FLATTEN(" + COL_NAME + ":" + element_res.getColumnValue(1) + ", RECURSIVE=>true) f n" +
                         "WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(f.path, '.+(\\w+\\[.+\\]).+', 'SubArrayEle') != 'SubArrayEle' ";  // This prevents return of elements of nested arrays (the entire array will be returned in this case)


      while (array_res.next()) {
         if (array_res.getColumnValue(1).substring(1) == "") {              // The element path name is empty, so this is a simple array element
             if (simple_array_col_list != "") {
                simple_array_col_list += ", n";}
             simple_array_col_list += COL_NAME + ":" + element_res.getColumnValue(1);    // Start with the element path name
             simple_array_col_list += "[" + array_res.getColumnValue(4) + "]";           // Add the array index
             simple_array_col_list += "::" + array_res.getColumnValue(2);                // Add the datatype
             simple_array_col_list += " as " + alias_dbl_quote + element_res.getColumnValue(3) + "_" + array_res.getColumnValue(4) + alias_dbl_quote;   // And finally the element alias - Note that the array alias is added as a prefix to ensure uniqueness
             }
         else {                                                             // This is an object array element
             if (object_array_col_list != "") {
                object_array_col_list += ", n";}
             object_array_col_list += "a" + array_num + ".value:" + array_res.getColumnValue(1).substring(1);    // Start with the element name (minus the leading '.' character)
             object_array_col_list += "::" + array_res.getColumnValue(2);                                        // Add the datatype
             object_array_col_list += " as " + alias_dbl_quote + element_res.getColumnValue(3) + array_res.getColumnValue(3) + alias_dbl_quote;   // And finally the element alias - Note that the array alias is added as a prefix to ensure uniqueness
             }
      }

// If no object array elements were found then add the simple array elements to the 
// column list...
      if (object_array_col_list == "") {
          if (col_list != "") {
             col_list += ", n";}
          col_list += simple_array_col_list;
          }
// ...otherwise, add the object array elements to the column list along with a
// LATERAL FLATTEN clause that references the current array to the table list
      else {
          if (col_list != "") {
             col_list += ", n";}
          col_list += object_array_col_list;
          table_list += ",n LATERAL FLATTEN(" + COL_NAME + ":" + element_res.getColumnValue(1) + ") a" + array_num;
          }
   }
}

// Now build the CREATE VIEW statement
var view_ddl = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW " + VIEW_NAME + " AS n" +
               "SELECT n" + col_list + "n" +
               "FROM " + table_list;

// Now run the CREATE VIEW statement
var view_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:view_ddl});
var view_res = view_stmt.execute();
return view_res.next();
$$;
```

> I tried this approach but it is displaying an error that regex has the [link I followed ][1]error.

- REGEX ERROR*
  [1]: https://www.snowflake.com/blog/automating-snowflakes-semi-structured-json-data-handling-part-2/#

I am getting this error:

```
JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
in CREATE_VIEW_OVER_JSON at ' var path_name = "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(f.path,'\[(.+)\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"')" ;' 
position 82
```

Comment: Please update your question to directly include all relevant information, including the error message, rather than linking to an article

Comment: I am getting this error. JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in CREATE_VIEW_OVER_JSON at ' var path_name = "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(f.path,'\\[(.+)\\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"')" ;' position 82

Comment: Ok - so instead of including all that irrelevant code in your question, please update your question to just include that one line, sample data for f.path and the result you want to achieve, based on that data

Answer (score 1):

Your error can be produced with just the first two line of the SP because you have you quotes incorrectly escaped/paired for the task:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_view_over_json (TABLE_NAME varchar, COL_NAME varchar, VIEW_NAME varchar, COLUMN_CASE varchar, COLUMN_TYPE varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$

var alias_dbl_quote = "";
var path_name = "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(f.path,'\\[(.+)\\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"')"   // This generates paths with levels enclosed by double quotes 
$$;

call create_view_over_json(null,null,null,null,null);
```

gives:

> 100131 (P0000): JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in CREATE_VIEW_OVER_JSON at 'var path_name = "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(f.path,'\[(.+)\]'),'(\w+)','"\1"')" // This generates paths with levels enclosed by double quotes ' position 79

In SQL and in Javascript you cannot put the Quote you are using to wrap are "string" in the string without escaping. In SQL you can use `$$` or `'` so you have used `$$` for the stored procedure body. Where inside the JavaScript you can use `'`, `"`, `

Thus in this line you have used double quoutes, which means you can embed the single quotes, but those doubles you have in the string terminate the string..

```
"regexp_replace(regexp_replace(f.path,'\\[(.+)\\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"')"
                                                              ^   ^
```

Thus given you need to use both single and double you should wrap the string in back qoutes `

```
var path_name = `regexp_replace(regexp_replace(f.path,'\\[(.+)\\]'),'(\\w+)','"\\1"')`;
```